# Getting error while installing elasticsearch Statefulset

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-stack, elk

I am trying to install an elastic statefulset in my GKE cluster but it's throwing an error and am unable to identify the error here this is the log that I had got inside the pod. Can someone help me? I have given the error logs as well as the elasticsearch_statefulset.yml file.

```
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-12-16T09:30:49,473Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.d.SeedHostsResolver", "cluster.name": "k8s-logs", "node.name": "es-cluster-0", "message": "failed to resolve host [es-cluster-2.elasticsearch]",
"stacktrace": ["java.net.UnknownHostException: es-cluster-2.elasticsearch",
"at java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:800) ~[?:?]",
"at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1495) ~[?:?]",
"at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1354) ~[?:?]",
"at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1288) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.parse(TcpTransport.java:548) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.addressesFromString(TcpTransport.java:490) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.addressesFromString(TransportService.java:855) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.discovery.SeedHostsResolver.lambda$resolveHostsLists$0(SeedHostsResolver.java:144) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]",
"at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:651) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) [?:?]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) [?:?]",
"at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]"] }
```

This is the yml I used to configure the stateful set :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: StatefulSet
  metadata:
    name: es-cluster
    namespace: kube-logging
  spec:
    serviceName: elasticsearch
    replicas: 3
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: elasticsearch
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: elasticsearch
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: elasticsearch
          image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.1
          resources: {}
          ports:
          - containerPort: 9200
            name: rest
            protocol: TCP
          - containerPort: 9300
            name: inter-node
            protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
          - name: data
            mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          env:
            - name: cluster.name
              value: k8s-logs
            - name: node.name
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: discovery.seed_hosts
              value: "es-cluster-0.elasticsearch,es-cluster-1.elasticsearch,es-cluster-2.elasticsearch"
            - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
              value: "es-cluster-0,es-cluster-1,es-cluster-2"
            - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
              value: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
        initContainers:
        - name: fix-permissions
          image: busybox
          command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          volumeMounts:
          - name: data
            mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        - name: increase-vm-max-map
          image: busybox
          command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
        - name: increase-fd-ulimit
          image: busybox
          command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: data
        labels:
          app: elasticsearch
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        storageClassName: standard
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
```

Service file which I used :

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  namespace: kube-logging
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 9200
      name: rest
    - port: 9300
      name: inter-node
```

Output for kubectl get statefulset -n kube-logging es-cluster -oyaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-12-20T06:31:55Z"
  generation: 1
  name: es-cluster
  namespace: kube-logging
  resourceVersion: "43285"
  uid: a1730c94-1aa5-461c-ba73-9af617ea4c42
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  serviceName: elasticsearch-headless
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: cluster.name
          value: k8s-logs
        - name: node.name
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: discovery.seed_hosts
          value: es-cluster-0.elasticsearch
        - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
          value: es-cluster-0
        - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Xms512m -Xmx512m
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: elasticsearch
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: rest
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: inter-node
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          name: data
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      initContainers:
      - command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        image: busybox
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: fix-permissions
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          name: data
      - command:
        - sysctl
        - -w
        - vm.max_map_count=262144
        image: busybox
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: increase-vm-max-map
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      - command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - ulimit -n 65536
        image: busybox
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: increase-fd-ulimit
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  updateStrategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      partition: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
      name: data
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
      storageClassName: gold
      volumeMode: Filesystem
    status:
      phase: Pending
status:
  collisionCount: 0
  currentReplicas: 1
  currentRevision: es-cluster-6f5bd744c7
  observedGeneration: 1
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updateRevision: es-cluster-6f5bd744c7
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

Output for kubectl get svc -n kube-logging elasticsearch-headless -oyaml :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress":true}'
  creationTimestamp: "2021-12-20T06:31:40Z"
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
  name: elasticsearch-headless
  namespace: kube-logging
  resourceVersion: "43384"
  uid: 80d10b9b-1f22-48ce-ba39-7d5801dc91ee
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.8.4.128
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.8.4.128
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: rest
    nodePort: 30625
    port: 9200
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9200
  - name: inter-node
    nodePort: 30056
    port: 9300
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9300
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 35.222.11.96
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of the elasticserch Service as well?

Comment: hi, updated the svc as well

Comment: I answered, I think you are missing an headless service to your configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally to the service you created to expose elastic search outside the cluster, you also need an `headless` service so that each node / Pod of the elastic cluster can communicate with each other.

I would do the following:

First, inside the spec of the `StatefulSet`, change `spec.serviceName` to another value, such as for example `elasticsearch-headless`

Second. create the new service with the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  # must be the same as the StatefulSet spec.serviceName
  name: elasticsearch-headless
  namespace: kube-logging
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  # headless service, can be used by elastic Pods to contact each other
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: rest
    port: 9200
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9200
  - name: inter-node
    port: 9300
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9300
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
```

---

Some docs on [Headless Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services)

Also, you may be interested into checking [HELM Charts](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts) and [ECK](https://www.elastic.co/elastic-cloud-kubernetes) because there is several stuff ready to be used in order to deploy production-ready elastic search clusters.

Comment: thanks for the answer but this did not solve the issue.

Comment: Same error of before? Or did something change in the logs?

Comment: same error as before not able to understand what is happening

Comment: Can you add / check again the output of `kubectl get statefulset -n kube-logging es-cluster -oyaml` and also of `kubectl get svc -n kube-logging elasticsearch-headless -oyaml`?

Comment: updated the my question

Comment: The headless service is completely different from the example I suggested. It needs to be of type ClusterIP and with clusterIP: None. Without those two things, it is not an headless service

Comment: I want to access that elastic URL from outside its not possible if I use clusterIP that is why I used load balancer. I need to create a fluentd pod and then connect these fluentd with elasticsearch so if I give clusterIP it does not work as I am not able to connect to elastic service.

Comment: You can have 2 services like I said in my answer. One is a LaodBalancer and one an headless clusterIP service. There's nothing blocking you from having multiple services exposing the same Pods

Comment: so if I have 2 services I should mention those 2 in statefulsets ?

Comment: No, the StatefulSet need to mention only the headless service, as that is the service which will be used by Pods to communicate with each other. The other service, the LoadBalancer one, will just be used externally to reach the application as a whole, the StatefulSet does not need to know about its existence. Just create an headless service, put its name in the StatefulSet and then have an additional LoadBalancer service to reach, that's it

Comment: thanks i did this there were few others errors also managed to fix that